# WPF VisualBrush with mixed aspect ratio

Tags: wpf, diagramming, visualbrush

We are using the Mindfusion WPF Diagramming Component.  I require a Visualbrush which must be able to be used in a third-party component for diagramming.

We have horizontally-stretching lanes on the diagramming canvas. We must define a background color for this lane, and some text on the top-left corner, to be repeated on the x-axis.  The text must remain the same size while the rest of the lane is filled with color when the lane is re-sized.

Unfortunately, the only thing we can do is provide a Visualbrush to the diagramming component, which is then set as background for the lane.  It seems impossible to work with this restriction because I am unable to define a text with fixed size, repeating on the x-axis, while also having a color brush stretching, all within a single Visualbrush.  How can this be done?

Comment: It will help if you post samples of the code you've attempted, with pictures of the results, along with a mockup of the desired result you want, if possible.